# How to set jdk compiler compliance level to 10?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wish to compile my code with jdk 10 using eclipse IDE. For this I have added jdk-10.0.1 to installed jres and have selected that as my default

[image: jre 10].

But in the compiler compliance level I do not get 10 in the dropdown. If only I could download java 9 which is currently not possible I could have compiled the same using java 9. Also eclipse photon which is the latest one available does not have java 10 in the dropdown

[image: 9 in the dropdown].

### Question

How can I compile my code using java 10 with eclipse, since we need an upgrade from java 8 to java 10.

[Java 9 support not available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html)

[Eclipse photon download link](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/photon)

Comment: what is you eclipse version?

Comment: Photon is not the latest but the upcoming release. Java 9 is supported since Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) and Java 10 since Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a). If 9 or 10 is not in the dropdown, [upgrade your Eclipse IDE](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F).

Comment: Download the latest oxygen https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R2/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked with the latest version of oxygen eclipse. Thanks